# Destructuring with nested objects and default values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, declaration, destructuring

I'm using destructuring to declare some variables like this:

```
const { a, b, c } = require('./something'),
    { e = 'default', f = 'default'} = c;
```

Is there a way to make this into single line?
I've tried something like :

```
const { a, b, c = { e = 'default', f = 'default'} } = require('./something');
```

But it gives me an error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just replace `=` with `:`:

```
const {a, b, c: {e = 'default', f = 'default'}} = require('./something')
```

Demo:

```js
const { a, b, c: { e = 'default', f = 'default'} } = {a: 1, b: 2, c: {e: 3}}
console.log(`a: ${a}, b: ${b}, e: ${e}, f: ${f}`)
```

It prints:

```
a: 1, b: 2, e: 3, f: default
```

Comment: this doesn't work if you're destructuring using `const { a, b, c: { e = 'default', f = 'default'} } = {a: 1, b: 2}`, which raises a TypeError.

Answer (score 25):

The above code will not work if the object does not have c in it

```js
const { a, b, c: { e = 'default', f = 'default'}} = {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(`a: ${a}, b: ${b}, e: ${e}, f: ${f}`)
```

This will print out an error. 
For completion, you could as a simple "={}" as default

```js
const { a, b, c: { e = 'default', f = 'default'} ={} } = {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(`a: ${a}, b: ${b}, e: ${e}, f: ${f}`)
```

Comment: In above example what if I want to take c[0]? If c[0] is not there then it should return blank object.

const obj = { a: 'a', b: {}, c: [] }

Answer (score 4):

This example will help you to understand the destructing of `array` and `object` with **fallback** values.

You can use the `=` symbol for adding `fallback` or `default` value while destructing.

```js
const person = {
  firstName: 'Nikhil',
  address: {
    city: 'Dhule',
    state: 'MH'
  },
  /*children: [
    { 
      name: 'Ninu',
      age: 3
    } 
  ]*/
}

const { 
  firstName, 
  address: {
    city,
    state
  },
  children: { 
    0: { 
      name='Oshin' // Fallback for name is string i.e 'Oshin'
    }={} // Fallback for 1st index value of array is blank object
  }=[] // Fallback for children is blank array
} = person;
  
console.log(`${firstName} is from ${city} and his first child name is ${name}`);
```