# Destructuring with default intermediate values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to use default intermediate values in destructuring like:

```
const { (form = {}): data = {} } = {};
```

Any way to assign a default `{}` to `form`? Couldn't find, seems impossible.

Comment: do you have some examples of input and wanted results?

Comment: In what sense is that not being provided by `{ form: data = {} }`?

Comment: @NinaScholz the code is the input. I'd like to have `data` variable with default `{}`

Comment: @jonrsharpe in the example `form` is `undefined` and cannot be destructured further. If it's possible to assign it a default value `{}` I could destructure further

Comment: Right but that's what `{ form: data = {} }` does. The "form" gives the property name in the source, and then the `: data` gives the desired local symbol.

Comment: @Pointy as you see `form` is missing in the object being destructured

Comment: In the example form is not _being_ destructured further, just bound to data, which is why people are asking for clarifying examples.

Comment: OK but as the symbol "form" is only used to indicate a source property name, what would it mean to give it a value? How would that end up different from providing the default for the desired symbol name ("data")?

Comment: also  [Destructuring with nested objects and default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049399/destructuring-with-nested-objects-and-default-values)

Comment: given your example optional chaining seems clearer. `return object.form?.data ?? {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the right syntax for [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) nested objects and a default value at the end.

```js
const getData = object => {
    const { form: { data = {} } = {} } = object;
    return data;
};

console.log(getData({}));
console.log(getData({ form: {} }));
console.log(getData({ form: { data: { foo: 42 } }}));
```

Comment: I agree, I realize now what you meant. This answer would be a *little* more informative if the default value for destructuring the "inner" object had some stuff in it instead of being simply `{ }`.